# Update config dynamically from front end react

Tags: reactjs

I need to update config or environment property from front end application without needing to rebuild application. Hence cannot use .env approach. If I inject config js directly from public folder..that possess risk...what is the other approach.

Answer (score 1):

Anything that is handled client side, is available publicly. If the config is not to be public, it needs to remain server side. There really is no in-between.